# -application:handleOpenURL: isn't getting called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, url, uiapplicationdelegate

I set `URLIdentifier` in my plist file but

`-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url`

method is not getting called?